# Password change every 90 days in MVC and SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I want a method to ask the user to change his password after having it for 90 days.

I have something like this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spRecoverPassword]
(
   @sUsername varchar(50),
   @sPassword varchar(100),
   @sPasswordSalt varchar (128)
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    if (exists (select 1
                from USER
                where Username = @sUsername))
    begin
        update USER
        set Password_Salt = @sPasswordSalt,
            Password = @sPassword,
        where Username = @sUsername;

        select 1;
    end
    else 
    begin
        select -1;
    end
END
```

Then I have a method to call this stored procedure, from ASP.NET MVC. And somehow I would like to check the date that  the password was last changed and do so that if that date is 90 days higher than today it will redirect it to the recover pass again. How should I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Add a new column in users Table to save last modified date of password.
on Get method calculate the difference between Last modified date of password and today's date. and do what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

Very easy:

1. add a date field in USER table for example `last_changed`.
2. update `last_changed` with `now()` in the query
3. check days difference `DATEDIFF(now(),last_changed)>90`

Comment: I wanna use that DATEDIFF at the login right? 
I'm kinda new to SQL so, when I try to add a new column to my user table it come with null able value, which I don't want, how do I change it?

Comment: there is a check box called `Allow Nulls` uncheck it in management studio

Comment: I can´t it gives me the following error:

'USER' table
- Unable to modify table.  
ALTER TABLE only allows columns to be added that can contain nulls, or have a DEFAULT definition specified, or the column being added is an identity or timestamp column, or alternatively if none of the previous conditions are satisfied the table must be empty to allow addition of this column. Column 'last_changed' cannot be added to non-empty table 'USER' because it does not satisfy these conditions.

Comment: So first create it allow nulls, give them a default date for all, then change it back to not allow nulls

Comment: if you put a non-null constraint then SQL server would not know what to fill the existing records which makes sense